# How t extract last part of a text in python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

I have a column of  strings in `abcd@xxxxx@yyyyy@zzzz` format,in a dataframe column . I want to iterate over all the values of the column, split the value using delimiter and extract the last part in a newly created column . To do so, I tried the below approach :

data['Issues']=data.Summary.str.split('@')[-1]

Where, 'Issues' is the newly created column and 'Summary' is the column I am iterating over. However doing so , I am getting the below error:
KeyError: -1

Can anyone please help with the solution ?

Comment: Lookup string splitting: here is an example to figure it out: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-split/

Comment: `s.split('@')[-1]`

Comment: Here you find guidance: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex here:

```
result = input_str.split('@')[-1]
```